# PHP file at server file root can't find necessary folder

Tags: php, apache, content-management-system, digital-ocean

I am trying to install craft cms and I am getting the following error

```
Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in /var/www/index.php
```

This is what my index.php folder is looking like

```
<?php

// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../craft';

// Do not edit below this line
$path = rtrim($craftPath, '/').'/app/index.php';

if (!is_file($path))
{
        exit('Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that <strong><code>$craftPath</code></strong> is set correctly in '.__FILE__);
}

require_once $path;
```

The craft folder is only one directory above www and dont understand why it cant find it.

Here are the parts of  my apache2.conf file that I think make a difference, the file is big and and I can't figure out how to copy the whole thing in nano

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

DocumentRoot /var/www


ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
```

[image]

Comment: Im using Ubuntu on Digital Ocean and used there prebuilt lamp install.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$craftPath = './craft';
```

instead of

```
$craftPath = '../craft';
```

Comment: no dice, the folder is above it not in the same directory

Comment: I added a screenshot of the file directory.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have access to the directory.  Try to change the directory privileges.

```
chmod a+x ../craft
```

If that doesn't work just move it into the `www` folder and just set `$craftPath` to `'craft'`

Comment: Tried all combos no work i am getting this error when reseting apache root@cms:/var/www# sudo service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server config apache2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [Sun Feb 16 04:04:23 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Comment: I think the problem is the craft directory isn't in `www` (where the script is being executed), so you don't have access.  And you have tried moving it into the directory?

Comment: I just moved it into the www directory. Its there in my ftp and when I view it in ssh.

Comment: Alright, just set `$craftPath` to `'craft'` and it should work find.

Comment: Ill try it im just uploading the folder again since i zipped and uncompressed it when I uploaded it the first time.